# google-api-client gem error rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-client

We have a problem with the google-api-client gem in rails 3.0, ruby 1.9.2, rbenv and Ubuntu.
In local environment it runs like a charm but when we deploy to integration environment with capistrano it fails when its requiring google/api_client

In the GemFile we have:

```
gem 'google-api-client',      '~> 0.4.3', :require => 'google/api_client'
```

In the GemFile.lock:

```
google-api-client (0.4.3)
  addressable (>= 2.2.3)
  autoparse (>= 0.3.1)
  extlib (>= 0.9.15)
  faraday (~> 0.7.0)
  launchy (>= 2.0.0)
  multi_json (>= 1.0.0)
  signet (>= 0.3.1)
```

But in the command line:

```
gem which google-api-client
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library google-api-client
```

We installed the gem with bundler

The complete trace of the error is:

```
no such file to load -- google/api_client
activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'

activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
  lib/snrengine/searcher/google_searcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
  lib/snr_engine.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:350:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
  app/models/social_network_recommender.rb:52:in `search_in_social_networks'
  app/controllers/company/searches_controller.rb:31:in `social_network_search'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:461:in `_run__587315471593137746__process_action__3569589993426311357__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `call'
  rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
  routing-filter (0.2.3) lib/routing_filter/adapters/rails_3.rb:74:in `call'
  routing-filter (0.2.3) lib/routing_filter/adapters/rails_3.rb:74:in `recognize_with_filtering'
  rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:499:in `call'
  oa-core (0.3.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
  oa-core (0.3.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
  oa-core (0.3.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
  oa-core (0.3.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
  vendor/plugins/bacchanalytics/lib/bacchanalytics.rb:64:in `call'
  exception_notification (2.5.2) lib/exception_notifier.rb:25:in `call'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.2.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
  activerecord (3.0.19) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
  activerecord (3.0.19) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
  activerecord (3.0.19) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
  activerecord (3.0.19) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
  activerecord (3.0.19) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
  rack (1.2.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (3.0.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
  railties (3.0.19) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
  rack (1.2.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.0.19) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.2.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `block in call'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  rack (1.2.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `call'
  railties (3.0.19) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
  railties (3.0.19) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:530:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:604:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:487:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:498:in `maintain_worker_count'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:272:in `join'
  unicorn (4.2.1) bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/jobssy-dev/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `load'
  /home/jobssy-dev/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `<main>'
```

It seems to be a dependencies problem but it has no sense as in development environment it runs

Comment: Start by verifying that the gem is getting installed by bundler in your deployment environment. It's very possible that capistrano has skipped the `bundle install` step somehow and the `google/api_client` require just happens to be the first to fail.

Comment: This was the first thing I tryed. I ran 'bundle install' in integration and the google-api-client was yet installed (my deployment capistrano script did it for me)